# paypal chained payment ipn not returning notification

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the following code for PayPal chained payment

```
require_once ("paypalplatform.php");
$amount=100;
$amt1=($amount * 10 )/100;
$amt2=$amount-$amt1;

$actionType         = "PAY";
$cancelUrl          = "http://test.com/test";

$returnUrl          = "http://test.com/test";
$currencyCode               = "USD";

$receiverEmailArray = array(
        'a***********_per@gmail.com',
        'a***********_biz@gmail.com'
        );

$receiverAmountArray = array(
        $amt1,
        $amt2
        );

$receiverPrimaryArray = array();

$receiverInvoiceIdArray = array(
        '1',
        '2'
        );

$senderEmail                    = "a************_per@gmail.com";        
$feesPayer                  = "";
$ipnNotificationUrl             = "http://test.com/paypal/buynow.php";
$memo                       = "";       
$pin                        = "agalameex";      
$preapprovalKey                 = "";       
$reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError          = "";   
$trackingId                 = generateTrackingID();
$resArray = CallPay ($actionType, $cancelUrl, $returnUrl, $currencyCode, $receiverEmailArray,
                        $receiverAmountArray, $receiverPrimaryArray, $receiverInvoiceIdArray,
                        $feesPayer, $ipnNotificationUrl, $memo, $pin, $preapprovalKey,
                        $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError, $senderEmail, $trackingId
);

$ack = strtoupper($resArray["responseEnvelope.ack"]);
if($ack=="SUCCESS")
{
    if ("" == $preapprovalKey)
    {
        // redirect for web approval flow
        $cmd = "cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" . urldecode($resArray["payKey"]);
        RedirectToPayPal ( $cmd );
    }
    else
    {
        // payKey is the key that you can use to identify the result from this Pay call
        $payKey = urldecode($resArray["payKey"]);
        // paymentExecStatus is the status of the payment
        $paymentExecStatus = urldecode($resArray["paymentExecStatus"]);
    }
} 
else  
{
    //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
    //TODO - There can be more than 1 error, so check for "error(1).errorId", then "error(2).errorId", and so on until you find no more errors.
    $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["error(0).errorId"]);
    $ErrorMsg = urldecode($resArray["error(0).message"]);
    $ErrorDomain = urldecode($resArray["error(0).domain"]);
    $ErrorSeverity = urldecode($resArray["error(0).severity"]);
    $ErrorCategory = urldecode($resArray["error(0).category"]);

echo "Preapproval API call failed. ";
echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorMsg;
echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
echo "Error Severity: " . $ErrorSeverity;
echo "Error Domain: " . $ErrorDomain;
echo "Error Category: " . $ErrorCategory;
```

}

In the above code every thing is working fine except return notification ( $ipnNotificationUrl). I am not getting any notification from the $ipnNotificationUrl when a payment is done. Can any body help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your IPN history in PayPal.  If it shows anything other than 200 response code you know something is wrong with your IPN listener.

You can check your web server logs to see exactly what error is happening when the script is hit.

Alternatively, you could setup a simple HTML form with hidden fields that match what you'd expect to get from PayPal.  Then you can submit this in a browser so you can see the result on screen.

Keep in mind that testing this way will result in an INVALID response back from PayPal because the IPN data did not come from their server, but you can adjust for that accordingly for testing purposes, get your issues fixed, and then you'll be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Debugging tips: check your IPN configuration at the PayPal backend. Replace your script by a simple script that just shows you when it's called and with what input.

Comment: A downvote but no comment? Useful. My mind-reading module is not yet enabled.